# Is it better to use type methods rather than instance methods if you don't need multiple instances

Tags: swift, oop

I'm getting to grips with understanding OOP

Is it better to use `MyClass.myFunction()`, where

```
class MyClass {
   static func myFunction() {
      // Do suff
   }
}
```

Or is it better to do `MyClass().myFunction()`, where

```
class MyClass {
   func myFunction() {
      // Do suff
   }
}
```

For me, I don't need to have multiple instances, so should I be sticking with the first one?

Comment: What you should consider is if you will need to access an instance of your `MyClass` or not.

Comment: Nope, I don't need to

Comment: Usually protocol requirements are instance properties/functions, which can't be met by static functions of a type like this. I would suggest using a singleton object, for those cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice to write instance methods vs static methods is less about the number of instances you intend on creating, and more about what the method actually needs to do.  If your method needs to access any properties of the instance it's being called on then it obviously needs to be an instance method.  If no properties need to be accessed, and the method is a helper related to the class, for example, then a static method might make sense.

For example:

```
class MyClass {

   var id: String

   init(id: String) {...}

   func printId() {
      print(self.id)
   }

   static func className() -> String {
      return "MyClass"
   }

}
```

This would allow you to get the name of the class without having an instance by calling the static method `MyClass.className()`.  If you had an instance and wanted the `id` you could call the instance method `printId`.

```
let instance = MyClass(id: "abc")
instance.printId() //prints "abc"
```

This is obviously an oversimplified example, but it illustrates one of the most basic questions you need to ask when deciding how to declare the methods.

As a better example of a good use of a static method, you might have a static method that is responsible for fetching the data needed to instantiate your class from an external API.  This makes most sense as a static method since you won't have what you need to create an instance until the API call is complete (and comes back with all the properties you need).

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton pattern. Something like this:

```
class MyClass{
   static let sharedInstance = MyClass()
   private init(){} //Make your constructor private

   func myFunction() {
      // Do suff
    }
}
```

and then access like this:

```
MyClass.sharedInstance.myFunction()
```

Only one instance of your class will exist. You may add other properties and functions.